# Diffing base Linux system to current state to produce playbook/dockerfile/shell script?

Tags: linux, installation

I'm looking for a way to produce an installation script out of diffing the current state of a Linux system to a base image (e.g., a Docker image). The output would be a list of operations that recreate the current state from the base image - typically a bunch of `apt-get install` and a bunch of file patch applications.

Is this even feasible? Is there such a thing today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is [possible](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#create).

Use **[Blueprint](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/)**.

> Blueprint is a simple configuration management tool that
>   reverse-engineers servers. It figures out what you’ve done manually,
>   stores it locally in a Git repository, generates code that’s able to
>   recreate your efforts, and helps you deploy those changes to
>   production.

http://devstructure.com/blueprint/blueprint-diff.1.html

Comment: Thanks! Marking this as the right answer - even though the Github project seems inactive: https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint

Answer (score 0):

I used to work on a disaster recovery product sold by EMC as HomeBase which did exactly this sort of thing (although never supported apt/dpkg packaged linux).  Making it work reliably is HARD.

If you're happy to just reinstall the same set of packages then you should be able to pull out the list of manually installed ones easily enough:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages

I don't know of any simple solutions out there for comparing /etc contents with base /etc contents.  Even then some of the changes may come from package installations and you'd have to be careful not to apply the changes multiple times.

Your best bet is likely to rebuild the system manually but carefully taking note of all operations performed - possibly using some version control system to track /etc changes.  If you can't rebuild manually then you could always look into creating a docker base image:
https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/